# How to deal with two-word last names in alphabetical citestyle with more than 3 authors

Tags: biblatex, citing

In my work I want to cite a paper with more than three authors but one author has a two-word last name as in the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber,citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
  author = {Obama, Barack and Author, Alpha and Buthor, Beta and Cuthor, Gamma},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}

@article{key2,
  author = {De Gaulle, Charles and Author, Alpha and Buthor, Beta and Cuthor, Gamma},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\cite{key2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this produces
[image: twoword last name in bib]

The last name "De Gaulle" produces as first three letters "De ". Aside from the messy layout there can be issues because with this space the citation becomes breakable:

[image]

Is there any common recommodation how to deal with this problem? I also tried to find a example of an alphabetical citation of the same paper in already existing publications, but it seems that it is very usual to use the numerical citestyle.

Comment: If you can choose, I think that the best solution is not use this bizarre style.

Comment: Yes I can choose. But in my opinion a numeric citestyle is annoying because one always has to look in the bibliography at the end, because the number-to-reference relation is harder to remember.

Comment: For this reason many journals use the author-year style (eg: `Smith et al. (2015)`  that imho is much better that see a strange kind of key code as `[Smi+05]`). Moreover, as in many journal too, you can link the cites with the references and references with cites (back references, showing the pages where the reference is cited) so it is very comfortable to check the references,  both on PDF and on paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how the author styles themselves and national conventions it may be appropriate to write

```
author = {de Gaulle, Charles},
```

instead of  `author = {De Gaulle, Charles},`.

If the name prefix starts with a lowercase letter, `biblatex` recognises it as a name prefix and uses different rules.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
  author    = {Obama, Barack and Author, Alpha and Buthor, Beta and Cuthor, Gamma},
  year      = {2002},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{key2,
  author    = {de Gaulle, Charles and Author, Alpha and Buthor, Beta and Cuthor, Gamma},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{key,key2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Oba+02; Gau+01]]

If you then use the option `useprefix=true,`, i.e.

```
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber, useprefix=true,]{biblatex}
```

you get

[image: [Oba+02; dGau+01]]

---

If it is not appropriate to use a name prefix here, you can tell `biblatex` to at least ignore the space for label generation with `\DeclareNolabel`. The default setting `\nolabel{\regexp{[\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}]+}}` only ignores punctuation, symbols and control characters. We can ignore spaces by adding `\p{Z}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex} 

\DeclareNolabel{
  \nolabel{\regexp{[\p{P}\p{S}\p{C}\p{Z}]+}}
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
  author    = {Obama, Barack and Author, Alpha and Buthor, Beta and Cuthor, Gamma},
  year      = {2002},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{key2,
  author    = {De Gaulle, Charles and Author, Alpha and Buthor, Beta and Cuthor, Gamma},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{key,key2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Oba+02; DeG+01]]

---

If none of these options float your boat, you can still override the name part of the label locally with `label`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex} 


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
  author    = {Obama, Barack and Author, Alpha and Buthor, Beta and Cuthor, Gamma},
  year      = {2002},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{key2,
  author    = {De Gaulle, Charles and Author, Alpha and Buthor, Beta and Cuthor, Gamma},
  label     = {Gaul},
  year      = {2001},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{key,key2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Oba+02; Gaul01]]